# Rear fender angle

Tags: fenders

For a 20" rear wheel with a this kind of fender, what would be the best angle to install it to minimize the spray on one's butt/legs?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's too short  - can't you extend it with some creative milk-jug-cutting or wood bending?

Comment: @RoboKaren, I probably can. Just wondering if it were to stay that short, I guess

Comment: Those things are mostly for show.  While they will do some catching of water, they're worse than a full mudguard, and most are only mounted on one arm so they're fragile.  Not something I want near my wheels!   Ideally you want guards that are sized as a just-over-half-wheel on the rear and a third of a wheel on the front.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are bikes like these generally used for? I'm assuming they aren't that good for distance due to the small wheel size and I'm not even sure where I would begin googling.

Comment: @Pants they look like [folding bikes](https://www.google.com/search?q=folding+bike&tbm=isch) to me.

Comment: Folding bikes are great for multimodal transport (i.e. bike to the train station then carry the bike onboard), for apartment dwellers, or for commuters who want to bring their bike indoors.

Comment: @pants that's probably a good question in its own right.  We have questions about folding bikes, but not one about why they exist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The spray will come off at a tangent to the wheel. If you're trying to prevent your back getting wet, putting the short fender to the rearmost position is the best but your legs will still get spray. If you want to prevent your butt getting wet, raise it a little. Note that going faster will mean the wind will push the spray back a little, but the spray will also increase in velocity and strength.

[image: Fender spray]

Unfortunately, your fender on your bike as-is is too short to protect your entire body and legs. You could make your own fender extension using milk jugs, wood, metal sheeting, plastic sheeting, coroplast, or any other number of DIY materials.

Note: Image is from a [website selling a fender for bicycles.](http://ch5778.wixsite.com/quickguard)

Comment: Ah. So when it comes to the pictures I've attached, the first one would protect the butt/thighs; the third, the back?

Comment: Pretty much.  I'd put it into the rearmost setting as it's easy to jerry-rig something else to protect the butt and thighs.